# SELECT ... WHERE ... query in CouchDB + Python

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm new to `CouchDb`. When I installed it, I thought it would be something like `MongoDb`, but mongo now seems to be more transparent than couch. At least, in mongo I could insert and get data almost right away, using find(), in couch I do not see such a simple way of doing a query. So, imagine, that I saved a document

```
{'type':'post','theme':'blabla'}
```

And now I need to query all posts. How would I do that in `Python` (using couchdb module)?

Comment: Queries are done via "Views" in CouchDB, a completely different concept. In the end you do not traverse the data, you traverse the B-Tree created by your View. A explanation from SQL to CouchDB can be found here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try creating a view.

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.type) {
    emit(doc.type);
  }
}
```

See here for more information on views: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html

Next, write some python.  I only have experience with the [cloudant-python](http://cloudant-labs.github.io/cloudant-python/) library which would look something like this:

```
import cloudant

account = cloudant.Account('http://localhost:5984')
db = account.database('yourdb')

view = db.view('theview')
options = {
    'key': 'post',
    'include_docs': True
}
for row in view.iter(params=options):
    # emits only rows with the key 'post'
    # with each row's emitting document
```

Note: this should also work for CouchDB

Comment: How to create the view programmatically? (I think it's different in python-cloudant than in python-couchdb)...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can use is a Mango Query:

First, let's make the database and save your document (using `save`, `create` is deprecated):

```
import couchdb
s = couchdb.Server()  # this is http://localhost:5984/ by default
db = s.create('posts')
db.save({'type': 'post', 'theme': 'blabla'})
```

We should have the setup OP described.

### Querying with `find`

```
for doc in db.find({'selector': {'type': 'post'}}):
    # process your doc
    print(doc)
```

That's it!
Read more about the possibilities here: http://localhost:5984/_utils/docs/api/database/find.html

Note, that the JSON query is passed as a normal Python `dict`.
The `selector` can have multiple conditions, not only on equality:

```
db.find({'selector': {'type': 'post', 'theme': {'$regex': '^bla'}})
```

### Don't forget the index

If you were using the API directly, you would get a warning in the result.
The query didn't use an index! For larger DBs this would be slow.

Creating the index programmatically was a challenge, but I learned how to do it via source diving (you don't need to do it often - it's a DB administration task, and you can do it with Fauxton UI).

Here's how to access and see indexes:

```
idx = db.index()
```

To display:

```
>>> list(idx)
[{'ddoc': None,
  'name': '_all_docs',
  'type': 'special',
  'def': {'fields': [{'_id': 'asc'}]}}]
```

And now create a new one, on `type`:

```
idx[None, None] = ['type']
```

(passing None will generate a random Design Document, and a random name for the index (UUIDs)):

```
>>> list(idx)
[{'ddoc': None,
  'name': '_all_docs',
  'type': 'special',
  'def': {'fields': [{'_id': 'asc'}]}},
 {'ddoc': '_design/3298cb694b9b0e42b2a70030ece92eca87d3552d',
  'name': '3298cb694b9b0e42b2a70030ece92eca87d3552d',
  'type': 'json',
  'def': {'fields': [{'type': 'asc'}]}}]
```

If you will be filtering on `theme`, you can add that, too:

```
idx['ddoc_theme_idx', 'theme_idx'] = [{'theme': 'asc'}]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> list(idx)
[{'ddoc': None,
  'name': '_all_docs',
  'type': 'special',
  'def': {'fields': [{'_id': 'asc'}]}},
 {'ddoc': '_design/3298cb694b9b0e42b2a70030ece92eca87d3552d',
  'name': '3298cb694b9b0e42b2a70030ece92eca87d3552d',
  'type': 'json',
  'def': {'fields': [{'type': 'asc'}]}},
 {'ddoc': '_design/ddoc_theme_idx',
  'name': 'theme_idx',
  'type': 'json',
  'def': {'fields': [{'theme': 'asc'}]}}]
```

The index can be on multiple fields - just add more fields on the list, e.g.:

```
idx[None, None] = ['type', 'theme']
```